# Slick slider should only show 4 slides. However part of a 5th slider is showing when it should not

Tags: javascript, html, slider, slick.js

[image]

I am creating a slider of properties, I am using the slick slider library. However part of the next slide is showing and part of the last slide is cut off.

I only want 4 slides to appear at desktop level.

I have tried stackoverflow and googling solutions with no luck.

https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/VoXGmR - To run the code you will need to open the codepen in firefox and have an add on to allow CORS to view the slider in action.

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the  slider elements inside a div fixed the layout issues.